# Randomising Numbers in a Grid

Tags: algorithm, permutation

The view of my application displays a grid of 16 numbers. Every time a button is pressed I want the arrangement of the numbers to change, and be random every time. The application works by having 16 small UIImageViews, each with an image (the number) associated with it. At the moment I 'randomise' the arrangement by generating a random number and having that number correspond to a particular arrangement. Like this:

```
int  number = rand() % 7;

if (number == 1) {
    space1.image = three;
    space2.image = ten;
    space3.image = one;
    space4.image = eight;
    space5.image = two;
    space6.image = five;
    space7.image = thirteen;
    space8.image = six;
    space9.image = four;
    space10.image = fifteen;
    space11.image = sixteen;
    space12.image = nine;
    space13.image = fourteen;
    space14.image = eleven;
    space15.image = twelve;
    space16.image = seven;
}
else if (number == 2) {
    space1.image = ten;
    ................
    .............etc
```

Obviously there are millions of possible arrangements and I am only capturing 7 of them here. Can anyone suggest a way of truly randomising the arrangement?

I hope I have been clear enough. Thanks in advance for any help.

George

Answer (score 1):

You could simply implement the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Instead of having multiple combination hard-coded, you have a default combination and when you apply the algorithm on it, it gets transformed to a random permutation.

You could implement it this way for example :

```
NSMutableArray * space; // Array containing your UIImageViews
// Initial combination
[(UIImageView *)space[0] setImage:one];
[(UIImageView *)space[1] setImage:two];
...
[(UIImageView *)space[14] setImage:fifteen];
[(UIImageView *)space[15] setImage:sixteen];

[self fisherYatesShuffle:space];
```

The FisherYates Shuffle implementation would be:

```
 - (void)fisherYatesShuffle:(NSArray *) array {
    for(int i = array.count - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        int j = arc4random() % i;
        [space exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you change a certain element of a non-mutable array? Also, why are you reinventing the wheel and not using `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`?

Comment: You're totally right, I just mixed things up by implementing half the function in C. I will edit right now.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I like the implementation of the FisherYates Shuffle, one thing I'm not too sure about though; you've got `space[1].image = one;` but surely 'image' isn't a property of an array?

Comment: Would you be able to explain this to me please?

Comment: space is an NSMutableArray _containing UIViews only_. space[1] is an UIView. space[1].image is the image property of the UIView.

Comment: I've realised there was an error in my initial question. My view is made up of sixteen UIImageViews, not UIViews. I've updated the question. Does this change anything? `space[1].image = one;` gives the error: "Property 'image' not found on object of type 'id'"

Comment: No it doesn't. And you are right, it should work if you cast the elements back to _UIImageView_. Try this: `[(UIImageView *)space[1] setImage:one]`

Comment: It no longer throws up an error, but it doesn't seem to do anything though. Just to check, am I setting up my NSMutableArray right? I've got `NSMutableArray *space` in .h and then I fill it with:       `[space addObject:space1];`                                                 
`[space addObject:space2];`
.... and so on.
Afterwards I then do `[(UIImageView *)space[1] setImage:one]`

Comment: Hmm you should allocate it at some point. `NSMutableArray * space = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:16];`

Comment: Okay thanks, that has sorted out the initial creation of the array. When it now tries to run the fisheryatesshuffle the app crashes giving the error **'NSRangeException', reason: -[NSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]'** I understand what this means, but I don't understand where index 16 is coming from?

Comment: Yes indexes are from 0 to 15 and not from 1 to 16. I just corrected the answer above. Have a look.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. The crash is when the fisheryatesshuffle method actually runs... Could there be something wrong in the method?

Comment: Something just occurred to me; although this algorithm will mix up the order the UIImageViews are in the array, will it actually change where the images appear on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making 16 identical instance variable, store the `UIImageView` object in an array, the `UIImage` objects in a mutable array, and randomize the elements of the image array:

```
NSMutableArray *imageViews, *images;

imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    UImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    [imageViews addObject:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d"], i];
    [images addObject:image];        
}

- (void)randomize
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int idx1 = arc4random() % images.count;
        int idx2 = arc4random() % images.count;
        [images exchangeObjectAtIndex:idx1 withObjectAtIndex:idx2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesViews.count) {
        [[imageViews objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint in C, because this is not really specific to Obj-C or IDE you're using.

```
Image images[n];
numbers = {0, 1, 2, /* ... n - 1 */ };

shuffle(numbers);
Images pmut[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pmut[i] = images[numbers[i]];
}
```